# mongodb:find and update operator can combine to one sql command?

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql

I have a collection:`{"_id":1,"a":3,"b":5，“a+b”:0}`

I want to do this:

```
y=db.collection.find({"_id":1},{"a":1,"b":1})
sum=y["a"]+y["b"]
db.collection.update({"_id":1},{"$set":{"a+b",sum}})
```

so collection will be: `{"_id":1,"a":3,"b":5,"a+b":8}`

can I combine the two operator to one sql command?

Comment: Funny that you should ask about SQL commands for a NoSQL DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do it in one command, because mongodb doesn't support field references in updates.